# email form select llist menu

Tags: php, javascript

i have a select list menu that i use in my email form:

```
<select name="orgSelect" class="orgSelect">
<option value="0">----Select product----</option>
<option value="1">Product 1</option>
<option value="2">Product 2</option>
<option value="3">Product 3</option>
</select>
```

But when the email form is sent its posts the value and I don't want him to get the value, but yes the item label in front "Product 1"..., the Value of the options is using ofr another thing, can someone tell me how to get the data "Product 1" or Product 2...

Comment: Are you using a database with your application or are you hardcoding it? Why don't you put the text you want in the value?

Answer (score 0):

Either don't use the `value=` attribute at all, which will have the client send the name of the option instead (but you don't get the actual number (guessing this is ID) of the product).

Or, a better solution, query your database for the product ID before sending the email, and get the Product name from there.

Comment: im sugin this script to crete my cascade, but if i put the text inside of the values it doesnt work

http://snipplr.com/view/26338.32931/

Answer (score 0):

you set like this

```
<select name="orgSelect" class="orgSelect">
<option value="0-0">----Select product----</option>
<option value="1|Product 1">Product 1</option>
<option value="2|Product 2">Product 2</option>
<option value="3|Product 3">Product 3</option>
</select>
```

and get post value like this

```
  var arr=explode('|',$_post['orgSelect']);
  var arrval=arr[0];
  var arrname=arr[1]
```